# ANTLR4 parser rules with other parser rules as arguments (meta-rules)

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I would like to be able to write a "meta-rule" in ANTLR4 that takes a rule as an input argument and performs a set modification to that rule. Here's an example grammar:

```
grammar G;

WS: [ \t\n\r] + -> skip;
CHAR: [a-z];
term: (CHAR)+;
sum: term ('+' term)+;
pterm: '(' term ')' | '(' pterm ')';
psum: '(' sum ')' | '(' psum ')';
expr: term | sum | pterm | psum;
```

The rules for `pterm` and `psum` perform the same action on `term` and `sum`, enclosing them in possibly nested parentheses. I would like to be able to replace the last three lines above with something like the following:

```
enclose[rule]: '(' rule ')' | '(' enclose(rule) ')';
expr: term | sum | enclose(term) | enclose(sum);
```

Is there a way to construct a meta-rule like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is, no.

Better to resolve by refactoring the grammar and identifying the structurally significant terms:

```
expr: LPAREN sum RPAREN | LPAREN expr RPAREN ;
sum : term ('+' term)* ; // changed to Kleene star
term: CHAR+ ;

LPAREN : '(' ;
RPAREN : ')' ;
CHAR   : [a-z] ;
WS     : [ \t\n\r]+ -> skip ;
```

The `sum` rule will consume all `term`s, so the `expr` rule only needs to handle `sum`s.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that this isn't workable. I think I was trying to do too much in the parser. I've rewritten the (more complicated) parser to be more general and moved some of what I was trying to do to the parser handler.